# What changes had to be made to linux kernel in order to support ryzen 5000 series processor?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, hardware, x86, amd

AMD contributed patches to linux kernel during 2020 in order to make it run on ryzen 5000 series processor. Don't ryzen 5000 series processors implement x64 ISA? How are ryzen 5000 processors different from intel processors and ryzen 3000 series processors? What are the platform specific behaviors that an OS needs to be aware of in order to properly run on all these processors that implement the same ISA? What are the changes AMD contributed to linux kernel in order to support ryzen 5000 processors?

Comment: Some of your questions are not strictly Unix or Linux-related. Only the last question seems relevant to this site. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Kusalananda The other questions were meant to support the last question. What were the changes submitted by AMD and what were the reasons for those changes?

Answer (score 7):

Ryzen does indeed implement the x86-64 ISA, but it introduced a few changes which matter for a kernel such as Linux.

Ryzen 5000 is part of Ryzen Gen 3, which uses a new “family” identifier, 19h (the previous Ryzen generation was family 17h). Many of the patches involve adding support for this, even if that only involves telling the kernel that family 19h behaves like 17h:

- [Family 19h PCI ids](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b3f79ae45904ae987a7c06a9e8d6084d7b73e67f)
- [Zen-style initialisation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=753039ef8b2f1078e5bff8cd42f80578bf6385b0)
- [IBS Fetch fix](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=221bfce5ebbdf72ff08b3bf2510ae81058ee568b)
- [EDAC support](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b4210eab9164e3ea647b71e1049391177db9b215)
- [_PSD table support](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5368512abe08a28525d9b24abbfc2a72493e8dba) (this one involves disabling a quirk which is no longer needed)
- [RAPL support](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=a77259bdcb62a2c345914df659a1fbc421269a8b)
- [more RAPL support](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8a9d881f22d7a0e06a46a326d0880fb45a06d3b5)
- [energy reporting](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=00e1fc8247167f3cc298923a134a37f61e8ed495)

A number of patches touch code which is hosted in the kernel but isn’t part of the kernel, mostly around perf events:

- [Family 19h L3 PMU support](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e48667b865480d8bf0f1171a8b474ffc785b9ace)
- [`turbostat` support](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=33eb82251af9be47a625ca1578f44e596a3a0ca9)
- [using Zen 2 events on Zen 3](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=09b54b30ccdcd3e17cc13079f581b1a389b04939)
- [slice and core handling](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=87a54a1fd525f2af8d82becf583c7e836918cf22)

There isn’t much platform-specific behaviour on Ryzen Gen 3 so far really; [`init_amd_zn`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.5/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/amd.c#L917), the Zen initialisation function, is mostly tasked with setting a feature flag, which is only used for side-channel mitigations.

More generally, CPU support tends to be more about platform support rather than new “core” CPU features: handling new identifiers, supporting new power-management features, error detection and correction features, etc. Some platforms will involve more complex support, *e.g.* on a CPU with a new integrated GPU, or a CPU with a new core split requiring far more architectural reworking in the kernel itself (*e.g.* to support small v. large cores).